# Противоречивый перевод для незарегистрированного участника

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, регистрация

[image: Незарегистрированный, зарегистрировался сегодня]

Незарегистрированный участник, который сегодня зарегистрировался — это странно. В оригинале нижняя строка звучит так:

> Member since today

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Предложил](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/1830) перевод [утверждён]:

> Участник с сегодняшнего дня

Comment: Мне казалось, что-то такое обсуждали давненько. Но найти не могу. Перевод утвердил.